# updating the master/detail list view in android on data change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented the android master/detail flow template in android.  I have changed it so that it loads the data from database on first load. The list populates fine.

I have a refresh button which calls an asyncTask with a callback, which effectively updates the data using http and updates the database.  I now need to update the data in the list. I have tried several approaches to update the recyclerView but it just wont update. Any ideas.

```
    public void refreshWeatherCharts() {


    WeatherChartFetchData callbackservice = new WeatherChartFetchData(this) {
        @Override
        public void receiveData(boolean success) {
            if (success)

                WeatherChartListBuilder.loadData();
        //    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = ((RecyclerView) recyclerView).getAdapter();
            RecyclerView rc = (RecyclerView) recyclerView;
            rc.invalidate();

        }


    };
    callbackservice.execute(null, null, null);

}


    private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(WeatherChartListBuilder.ITEMS));
}
```

/////////

```
public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<WeatherChart> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<WeatherChart> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<WeatherChart> viewModels) {
        mValues.clear();
        mValues.addAll(viewModels);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void addItem(int position, WeatherChart viewModel) {
        mValues.add(position, viewModel);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mValues.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.weatherchart_list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }
```

Comment: You need to call `SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.updateData()`in your `refreshWeatherCharts()` method.

Comment: thanks for the replay.  When i add the statement, it doesnt recognise the updateData statement.  Do i have to declare it globally or initialise/ reference it some how?  Cheers

Comment: Managed to sort it.  I refactored the recyclerView to the following

Comment: This is not what I meant, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort it.  I refactored the recyclerView to the following:

```
 recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.weatherchart_list);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
     mAdapter = new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ITEMS);
 //   new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(ITEMS);
    //SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolde

    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new adapter each time some item's value changes in your data set or if you added new items to your data set, or removed items, or even if the whole list has changed. Just update the data set in your adapter which in your case is a `List` of `WeatherChart`s.

```
public void refreshWeatherCharts() {

    WeatherChartFetchData callbackservice = new WeatherChartFetchData(this) {
        @Override
        public void receiveData(boolean success) {
            if (success) {

                WeatherChartListBuilder.loadData();
                RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = ((RecyclerView) recyclerView).getAdapter();
                ((SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter) adapter).updateData(WeatherChartListBuilder.ITEMS);
            }
        }
    };

    callbackservice.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
viewAdapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();

viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```